# How to debug T-SQL from SDK-style C# test project under VS 2019?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, debugging, sql-server-data-tools, visual-studio-2019

I have two projects:

1. SQL Server Data Tools `.sqlproj` defining some T-SQL stored procedures, being deployed into a locally-installed SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition.
2. MSTest `.csproj` calling into these stored procedures via ADO.NET.

In Visual Studio 2017 Professional, with **old-style** test project, I was able to:

- turn-on the "Enable SQL Server debugging" in the test project properties,
- debug the method marked by `[TestMethod]` (by right-clicking in Test Explorer),
- and when I reach `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`, step-in into the T-SQL stored procedure and hit the breakpoint within T-SQL.

Since then, I have migrated the test project to the **new "SDK-style"** `.csproj` format, and to Visual Studio 2019 Professional, and I no longer see the "Enable SQL Server debugging" option anymore. Any breakpoints I try to set in T-SQL are marked as:

> *"The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."*

The key for me is the ability to debug across the boundary between C# and T-SQL, because C# prepares all the inputs for T-SQL. I know I can just write a T-SQL script that prepares the input and debug *that*, but that would duplicate the job already done by C# and would be difficult in some cases (such as concurrency testing).

So, is there a way (in this environment) to debug C# code and step into T-SQL?

---

Here is my new test project:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net47</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="1.4.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="1.4.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..." />
        ...
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="..." />
        ...
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Please check this [similar one](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/1125), in VS2017, the enable native code debugging is not available for sdk-format projects just like enable sql server debugging option. So I think you can post it to the team in github to ask for the support of debugging sql server in new project system for sdk-format.

Comment: To whom it may concern: I have filed an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/4935) and there now is a [PR](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/pull/5484) for it. Fingers crossed! :)